# Utilising variables in tail command

Tags: bash, tail

I am trying to export characters from a reference file in which their byte position is known. To do this, I have a long list of numbers stored as a variable which have been used as the input to a tail command.

For example, the reference file looks like:

```
ggaaatgcattcaaacatgc
```

And the list looks like:

```
5
10
7
15
```

I have tried using this code:

```
list=$(<pos.txt)
echo "$list"
cat ref.txt | tail -c +"list" | head -c1 > out.txt
```

However, it keeps returning "invalid number of bytes: '+5\n10\n7\n15...'"

My expected output would be

```
a
t
g
a
...
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling you are processing some part of a fasta file and the problem you are posting is an XY-problem. I.e. you are asking this question to solve another problem that might be solved more efficiently in an other way.

Comment: Biologically, the list represents the positions of variations (SNPs) to the reference file. The code is trying to find what the original character in the reference file is at those positions. I hope that helps

Comment: This approach will *not* work properly with fasta files, because `head`, `tail`, etc all work by character positions, not base positions. That is, they don't know to skip over the header, comments, or even the linefeed between lines. You really need tools that know how to parse fasta files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access your `list` variable in your tail command. You can access it like this: `$list` rather than just using quotes around it.

Your logic is flawed even after fixing the variable access. The `list` variable includes all lines of your `list.txt` file. Including the newline character `\n` which is invisible in many UIs and programs, but it is of course visible when you are manually reading single bytes. You need to feed the lines one by one to make it work properly.

Also unless those numbers are indexes from the end, you need to feed them to head instead of tail.

If I understood what you are attempting to do correctly, this should work:

```
while read line
do
  head -c $line ref.txt | tail -c 1 >> out.txt
done < pos.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your command failure is simple. The variable `list` contains a multi-line string stored from the `pos.txt` files including newlines. You cannot pass not more than one integer value for the `-c` flag.

Your attempts can be fixed quite easily with removing calls to `cat` and using a temporary variable to hold the file content

```
while IFS= read -r lineNo; do
    tail -c "$lineNo" ref.txt | head -c1
done < pos.txt
```

But then if your intentions is print the desired output in a new-line every time, `head` does not output that way. It just forms a string `atga` for your given input in a single line and *not* across multiple lines with one character at each line.

As Gordon mentions in one of the comments, for much more efficient FASTA files processing, you could just use one invocation of `awk` though (skipping multiple forks to `head`/`tail`). Your provided input does not involve any headers to skip which would be straightforward as

```
awk ' FNR==NR{ n = split($0,arr,""); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) hash[i] = arr[i] } 
      ( $0 in hash ){ print hash[$0] } ' ref.txt pos.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `cut` instead of `tail`:

```sh
pos=$(<pos.txt)
cut -c ${pos//$'\n'/,} --output-delimiter=$'\n' ref.txt
```

Or just awk:

```
awk -F '' 'NR==FNR{c[$0];next} {for(i in c) print $i}' pos.txt ref.txt
```

both yield:

```
a
g
t
a
```